# PHP Website - Save file to different folder as per path in visitor's folder

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I have core PHP website. In this, there are so many pdf files of products info and download button. So when the customer download the pdf, it should save as per server file path to the customer's system.

**EX:**

PDF File on server: **all-pdfs/gardens/lights/green-lights.pdf**

So when download this file, it should save at: **Downloads/all-pdfs/gardens/lights/green-lights.pdf**

Comment: You can't.  It's impossible to control the client saving path. All you can do is offer the file for download, it's up to the user where it will be saved.

Comment: It would be a huge security hole if you could arbitrarily write to user's systems. e.g. `C:\system32\hosts` then change routing path of something (assuming thats still a path in Windows?)

Comment: It is not possible... But my be you have some kind of special requirement that you need to implement and unable to explain well ?

Comment: At most you could use a container format such as ZIP or TAR, so that when the user downloads this to a "default" location on their system, it will unpack this using the path information given in the container format, _below_ that "default" location.